# VB.NET Class implements event

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, interface

I don't see what I did wrong.

The IDE tells me

```
 "Class 'CaptureDevice' needs to implement event 'Event NewFrame(sender As Object, e As CameraEventArgs) for 'IVideoSource'.
```

The class 'CaptureDevice' looks like this:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Net
Imports dshow
Imports dshow.Core

Namespace VideoSource

    Public Class CaptureDevice
        Implements IVideoSource
        Private source As String
        Private m_userData As Object = Nothing
        Private m_framesReceived As Integer

        Private thread As Thread = Nothing
        Private stopEvent As ManualResetEvent = Nothing

        ' new frame event '
        Public Event NewFrame As CameraEventHandler

        '(...)'
    End Class
End Namespace
```

My class 'IVideoSource' looks like this:

```
Namespace VideoSource

    'IVideoSource interface'
    Public Interface IVideoSource

        Event NewFrame As CameraEventHandler

    End Interface

End Namespace
```

Does anybody see where I went wrong or what may be missing?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Do you have another event declared in your interface with the signature `Event NewFrame(sender As Object, e As CameraEventArgs)`?

Comment: Is `CameraEventHandler` inside `VideoSource` namespace too?

Comment: This will be helpful to read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd43d244.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Implements` clause, so, something like:

```
Public Event NewFrame As CameraEventHandler Implements IVideoSource.NewFrame
```

VB.Net does not have c#'s implicit interface implementation.

Comment: That does not work. The IDE tells me "Events in interfaces may not be declared as 'Implements'.

Comment: @tmighty That can't be right. Are you sure you are declaring the event  in the exact same way?

Comment: @tmighty - it sounds like you're trying to apply the `Implements` to the interface definition. That's wrong. You apply it to the `Event` in `CaptureDevice`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `CaptureDevice` class, do this instead:

```
Public Event NewFrame As CameraEventHandler Implements IVideoSource.NewFrame
```

While C# assumes a public member with the same name of an implemented interface's member to be the implementation, VB.NET requires that implementations are declared explicitely.